# How to do paging with my sql in php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a application that was developed by previous developer. Now, in that application there are 17000 entries and the application has become slow. Its very slow like takes 10 mins to load all data.

I think it is because they are getting all data at once can just Paging by JS.

I want to change it and get first 10 entries for the first page and when user clicks on the Next page or Page 2 button there should be a query fired to get next 10 data.

Current Application Query:

```
SELECT bm.bank_name,b.bank_ifsc,e.emp_id,e.emp_code,e.first_name,e.middle_name,e.last_name,e.active_status as emp_status,e.account_no 
FROM tblemployee e 
Left Join tblbank_mst bm on bm.bank_id=e.fk_bank_id 
Left Join tblbank b on b.bank_ifsc_id=e.fk_bank_ifsc_id 
WHERE e.del_status=0 
AND e.role_id=4 
AND e.is_admin=0 
ORDER BY first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do few steps

Step 1: 
need to set `page` if its not in URL then set as `1` which means page 1 means first set of records

Step 2: 
set no. of records per page for example 5 records per page

Step 3: 
Calculate dynamically Starting record # for example 
    Page 1 : start from 1
    Page 2 : start from 6
    Page 3 : start from 11

and then append query like

```
SELECT bm.bank_name,b.bank_ifsc,e.emp_id,e.emp_code,e.first_name,e.middle_name,e.last_name,e.active_status as emp_status,e.account_no 
FROM tblemployee e 
Left Join tblbank_mst bm on bm.bank_id=e.fk_bank_id 
Left Join tblbank b on b.bank_ifsc_id=e.fk_bank_ifsc_id 
WHERE e.del_status=0 
AND e.role_id=4 
AND e.is_admin=0 
ORDER BY first_name
LIMIT $starting, $pagination
```

it will print

```
first page : LIMIT 1,5 
second page : LIMIT 6,5
third page : LIMIT 11,5
```

and so on.

In bottom area, you need to set navigation like

- First
- Back
- Next
- Last

That you need to set the page No based on current page.